# Prove: $x_{n}\rightarrow a\iff d(x_{n},a)\rightarrow 0$

Tags: metric-spaces

> Prove: $$x_{n}\rightarrow a\iff d(x_{n},a)\rightarrow 0$$

Intuitively and in euclidian metric it seems to be trivial, but I am stuck.

$(\Rightarrow):$ There for for all $\epsilon>0$ there is $n>N$ such that $d(x_{n},a)<\epsilon$

And I need to get to $d(d(x_{n},a),0)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $d$ is a metric, then $d(x_n,a)\ge0$. Therefore, you are given
$$
\text{for all }\epsilon\gt0\text{, there is an }N\text{ so that if }n\ge N\text{, then }0\le d(x_n,a)\lt\epsilon
$$
Thus, for $n\ge N$,
$$
d(d(x_n,a),0)=|d(x_n,a)-0|\lt\epsilon
$$
The outer $d$ is in $\mathbb{R}$ while the inner $d$ is in the other metric space.

Comment: Why can we say that the outer d is in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Because $d(x_n,a)\in\mathbb{R}$ and $0\in\mathbb{R}$, so the outer $d$ is measuring distance in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: A metric over a set $X$ is defined as : $$d:X\times X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$$ what ever your metric is.

Answer (score 2):

In $d(d(x_n,a),0)$ two $d$ are not the same metric. The last one is just $|d(x_n,a)|$ as is in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This is a comment to the question rather than an answer.

Comment: This is not a comment, this is the answer: as @gbox asked: $d(d(x_n,a),0)$ is required. my answer is $d(d(x_n,a),0)=|d(x_n,a)|=d(x_n,a)<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Okay, I see where you're going, but I think a bit more clarification might be useful. (+1)

Comment: I agree. I also needed to put that a metric on $X$ is $d:X\times X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.